# How to enable 2 HTTP servers on the same LAN to discover each others

Tags: networking, rust, httpserver

I have 2 apps written in rust each app run on different machine but these 2 machines connected to the same router/LAN

What I need to do is to **enable one app to programmatically discover the IP of the other one** (port already known)

An easy way to do it could be by listing all IPs on the LAN and then sends a request to each IP and and depending on the response I will know if this is the server or not, I don't know if this is the best solutions first second I don't know how to list the IPs on the same LAN in rust.

Comment: Can you broadcast a UDP packet and have the other server respond with its IP?

Comment: Or via some type of multicast

Comment: "listen to all the ips on the network" - I hope you are aware on how big private networks can be; there are private subnets with the subnet mask 255.0.0.0, meaning 256*256*256 = 16777216
IP addresses

Comment: Usually you use DNS to solve these kinds of problems. If the network is trusted, mDNS could be a viable solution.

Comment: Use multicast. Each could subscribe to a group, and you could send a message to the group. The response to the multicast message could contain the unicast address.